# Crafting an InputIterator that does not store the value_type

Tags: c++, iterator, input-iterator

I am creating a type that models `InputIterator`.  In my application, "skip the first hundred thousand elements" is a reasonable thing to do, and creating the `value_type` is expensive, so I want my iterator to create the `value_type` only when dereferenced, not when incremented.

I could easily make `operator*` return the `value_type` by value.  But I do not know what to do about `operator->`.  How can I return a pointer if my iterator is not storing the `value_type`?  I'm afraid of lifetime problems with a pointer-to-temporary, and don't want to get burned.

I have thought about not providing `operator->`, but then I wouldn't have a complete `InputIterator`.

Comment: Why don't store a pointer to `value_type` in your iterator and allocate it only when needed? I mean something like `lazy loading` pattern.

Comment: You can still store an object of `value_type`, but only create it after the first dereference. With something like a [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional).

Comment: I'm in C++14 so I don't have `std::optional`, yet.  But even if I did, the value_type is large, and would make the iterator large, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it will work to return a proxy object by value from the iterator's `operator->`.  The proxy would have a single value_type data member, and its own `operator->` returning a pointer to that data member.

The lifetime of the proxy object is the same as any other return by value object (like my plan for `operator*`), so although I do have a pointer-to-temporary, in these circumstances it is consumed before the proxy object is destroyed.